# Difference between cumulative binomial probability and discrete

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am new to this so I don't know if this question is too obvious or not. I have this question (its already solved I'm just trying to understand why). Say you want to prove that less than 10% of US citizen is vegetarian. So your H0: at least 10% of US citizen is vegetarian and H1: less than 10% of US citizen is vegetarian. Assuming that you have a sample of 300 people and 21 of them is found to be vegetarian. The problem is solved using the R function pbinom(21,300,0.3), which to my knowledge is the binom function P(X<=21). Why do we use cumulative here? Can we use dbinom(21,300,0.3) instead? (just find the probability of getting 21 out of 300 with 0.3)

Answer (score 2):

**Binomial PDF and CDF in R.** First, let's look at `pbinom` and `dbinom` in R.

If $Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 5, p = 1/2),$ then
$P(Y = 2) = {5\choose 2}(1/2)^5 = 0.3125.$  In R you can
compute the formula for yourself or use the binomial PDF
function `dbinom`.

```
choose(5, 2)/2^5
[1] 0.3125
dbinom(2, 5, 1/2)
[1] 0.3125
```

Now, if you want $P(Y \le 2) = P(Y=0) + P(Y=1) + P(Y=2) = 0.5000,$
you need to compute each of the three probabilities on the right side
of the equation. You can do them individually, adding three results from
`dbinom` or with one application of the binomial CDF `pbinom`.

```
dbinom(0:2, 5, 1/2)
[1] 0.03125 0.15625 0.31250
sum(dbinom(0:2, 5, 1/2))
[1] 0.5
pbinom(2, 5, 1/2)
[1] 0.5
```

Next, for some terminology. It's not correct to say you want
to "prove that less than 10% of US citizen is vegetarian."
You can't *prove* anything for sure about the percentage of vegetarians
in the US by taking a random sample of 300 US citizens and testing a hypothesis. However, you *can* make a statement about your sample, that sheds
some light on that 10% hypothesis.

**One sided hypothesis test of binomial success probability.** If 10% of US citizens are vegetarian, then a sample of $n = 300$
should show *about* $X = 30$ vegetarians. In fact, you got $X = 21 < 30,$
which might make you think the percentage is less than 10%.

***Null disribution.*** Let's look at a plot of the distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n = 300, p = .1).$
This is called the 'null' distribution because it agrees with the equality
in the null hypothesis $H_0: p \ge 0.1.$ [By the way, the null hypothesis must *always* contain an $=$ sign; maybe as $=. \le,$ or $\ge.$ In this problem it would have been OK to write $H_0: p = 0.1.]$

```
plot(x, PDF, xlim=c(0,70), xaxs="i", type = "h", col="blue", lwd=3)
  abline(h=0, col="green2")
  abline(v=21, col="red", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Almost all of the probability in this distribution lies below 70, so I showed only probabilities from 0 through 70. The red vertical dotted line
shows the observed value $X = 21.$

***P-value of the test.*** In order to test $H_0: p \ge 0.1$ against $H_a: p < 0.1,$ we want to know not just the probability $P(X = 21),$ but the probability $P(X \le 21).$
Values below 21 would be even more convincing evidence for small percentages of vegetarians in the US, so all of them need to be included to make
a useful statement. The P-value of a test is the probability (based on $H_0)$ of getting a
value as or more extreme than the observed value, *in the direction(s)
of the alternative hypothesis.* [This is a one-sided alternative so we are only interested in values smaller than the observed 21.]

So assuming the true value is $p = 0.1$ specified in $H_0$ we seek
$P(X \le 21\,|\,p=0.1) = 0.0458 < 0.05.$ This is the P-value of the test.
Many times we test hypotheses at the 5% level, which means to reject
$H_0$ when the P-value is smaller than $0.05 = 5\%.$ In terms of the graph above, the P-value is the sum of the heights of the bars at and to the left of the vertical dotted line.

```
pbinom(21, 300, 0.1)
[1] 0.04580612
```

This is not 'proof' that the percentage of US citizens who are vegetarian is below 10%.  Your observed value gives you a point
estimate that $\hat p = X/n = 21/300 = 0.07,$ or 7%. We say that
the observed value 7% is 'significantly' smaller than the hypothetical 10% (or more).

---

*Notes:* (1) You have a typo in your question, $0.3$ instead of $0.1,$ which may have added to your confusion. Using that would have given you an incorrect

pbinom(21, 300, 0.3)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4VSZ.png) 7.664809e-23

(2) If you had observed $X = 25$ vegetarians out of $n = 300$ then your point estimate would have been $\hat p = 25/300 = 0.083$ or 8.3%. However, 8.3% is not 'significantly' smaller, at the 5% level, than the hypothetical 10% (even though it *is* smaller). The P-value of that observation would have been 0.19, which exceeds 0.05.

```
pbinom(25, 300, 0.1)
[1] 0.1949021
```

(3) In fact, $X = 21$ is the 'critical value' for rejection at the 5% level. It is the largest observed value that would still lead to rejection of $H_0.$ In particular, $X = 22$ would have given a P-value above 0.05.

```
pbinom(22, 300, 0.1)
[1] 0.06993984
```